# Installing Ubuntu 11.10 on HP Envy 15 - Partition Problems

Tags: installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu 11.10 on my HP ENVY 15, however I am getting some problems. When I come to the partitioning section of the installation I am given my 4 partitions that I have. 
I change the partition of my 450 gb to 420 gb, so that I can use that 30gb space that I free up to install Ubuntu on it. After I do this step, instead of seeing the keyword to the 30gb I see **unusable**.

I have read that there can not be more than 4 partitions somewhere for a UBUNTU installation, but that is not true, because I just installed Ubuntu 11.10 on my Lenovo which has the same amount of partitions as my ENVY ( I do get problems on my lenovo with installing ATI drivers but that is a completely different story).

Does anybody have an idea of why I am getting an **unusable** notification next to my freed up space?

Comment: I suspect that 'your four partitions that you have' are all primary, and yes, you can only have your four primary partitions. If that's the case, you'd have to delete one of your partitions and create some logical ones which don't have that limitation.

Comment: Is there a way to denote some of the partitions as "non-primary". Because I don't wanna delete a partitions just like that - might have some consequences

Comment: No, don't think so..., at least not without consequences.

Answer (score 1):

I have an HP DV6tSE which is a very similar laptop to your Envy15. They do share the same partitions layout. I used Wubi for a long because of this issue with 4 primary partition until a found a forum post on how to do it. Here's a Step by Step guide on what's need to be done to install Ubuntu on dual boot with Windows. http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11299287&postcount=5

Note: Your windows install will be deleted, but you can back up your files and bring them up again.